# Using windows variables (like %USERPROFILE%) in `NuGet.targets`?

Tags: nuget, targets

The current value of NuGet.exe (command line) (in `NuGetToolsPath`) is `$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.exe`

I would like to modify this value to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`

The question is, how to use windows variables in `Nuget.targets`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :)

Simply use `$(USERPROFILE)`

Follow the link for anyone interested:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459.aspx